# How to properly dispose of foreign soil?

Tags: waste, food-waste, biosecurity

Long story short, had some soil stuck to a vegetable that ended up passing customs (got waved through by the customs officer as they were reasonably confident there should be none present, despite offering to get it inspected) and when I looked it up later, it's a *big* no-no to import soil because of the potential for diseases to spread.

The soil in question is probably a spoonful or two at most, but I don't know if that means it's OK to ignore. Erring on the side of caution, probably not.

Right now it's currently separated from everything else (to the best of my ability), but the question now is - how do I dispose of this properly? [Soil is notoriously difficult to "kill"](https://biofortified.org/2013/10/how-to-kill-your-soil/) apparently, so I'm not sure what to do.

1. Is the amount of soil I've discovered going to pose a problem if I "just" throw it away in the trash or compost? Also considering the fact that this is a fairly large vegetable with a peel, does that affect the way I will have to dispose of it? Or am I making a mountain out of a molehill here?
2. What are my options to dispose of this, assuming it is in fact A Big Deal™?

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/105928/46 (it didn't get good answers in my opinion.) I would burn it outside if that's an easy option for you.